# How to integrate a secure monthly online pay service into my app

Tags: credit-card

I've created an app, I need to have willing users register for a more featured "pay version". How can I make a secure, online pay service while billing those users monthly, and telling my app that they are still on good credit with me. I'm looking for an online service, or an available code, will paypal do this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Payments will do this.  The user authorizes a maximum amount and will be billed monthly for $X until the maximum is reached.

You don't want to deal with this in-house.  Storing credit card numbers is a recipe for many types of disaster.

Comment: Storing credit cards in-house also would require you to pass PCI DSS audits which is a nightmare in itself - https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/

Answer (score 0):

Look for an API and http://yodlee.com/index2.shtml is solution for something like this i believe.